# Volume and surface area of a solid in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: area, volume, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Suppose that initially I have a right triangle in the $xy$ plane given by the points $a=(0,0)$; $b=(0,B)$ and $c=(B,B)$, such as shown below:

[image]

Since from now on, I will work with polar coordinates, I know that the are of this region can be evaluated as:
$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\int_{0}^{B/cos\theta}{rdrd\theta}}=\frac{B^2}{2}$$
Which is the same as the regular area of the triangle $A=bh/2$ just in polar coordinates. Now suppose that I have a solid of height $H$ where the face $bc$ is given by any generic function $z=f(r,\theta)$ (in cylindrical coordinates), while the others two faces ($ab$ and $ac$) are planes parallel to the $z$ axis. For instance, a solid like this can be visualized as the one below:

[image]

My question is on how can I write the equations for volume and surface area of this solid as a function of $f(r,\theta)$? So that I can evaluate these quantities for any $f(r,\theta)$. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Suppose for example that this figure is 1/8 of a pyramid trunk with a square base. How can I prove the volume and surface equations for the pyramid adopting cylindrical coordinates (similar to what I did with the triangle)?

Comment: “where the face $bc$ is given by any generic function $z=f(r)$” doesn't make sense to me.  Do you mean $r = f(\theta)$?  That would seem to generalize the case of a straight line face.  If so, the answer is just to replace $B/\cos\theta$ in the integral with $f(\theta)$.  There's no way to write the answer without an integral.

Comment: What I meant is, for example, if you consider the triangle $abc$ as 1/8 of a pyramid base, the inclined surface of the pyramid may be viewed as $z=f(r)$ (or $z=f(r,\theta))$, am I wrong? And yes, I'd like to express this surface area/volume as an integral.

Comment: Ah, OK.  In that case you would need $z=f(r,\theta)$.  What is $H$ then?  The maximum height of the solid?

Comment: Yes, sorry, H is the maximum height. The solid is limited by the planes $z=0$ and $z=H$, while $\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$. I edited the question for $f=(r,\theta)$.